# Recode '[.data.table'

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have an user defined object that has a class with 3 attributes.

```
i.e. > class(data)
     [1] "cumulative" "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I wish to recode `[` so that when I call it on my object it uses the `data.table` defined function i.e. `[.data.table` but returns my user defined class. How do I do this?

I tried creating a function as follows, and a few other variations but I can't get it to work

```
'[.cumulative' <- function(x,i,j,...) {
  y <- NextMethod(.Generic)(x,i.j)
  class(y) <- .Class
}
```

Comment: What particular problems are you facing with your current attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/64) has been fixed in the current development version `1.9.3`. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> If another class inherits from `data.table`; e.g. `class(DT) == c("UserClass", "data.table", "data.frame")` then `DT[...]` now retains `UserClass` in the result. Thanks to Daniel Krizian for reporting, #5296 (git [#64](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/64)). Test added.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
dt = data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
setattr(dt, 'class', c("foo", "data.table", "data.frame"))
class(dt)
# [1] "foo"        "data.table" "data.frame"

## bug...
class(dt[, .N, by=x])
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"

# -------------------------------

require(data.table) ## 1.9.3
dt = data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
setattr(dt, 'class', c("foo", "data.table", "data.frame"))
class(dt)
# [1] "foo"        "data.table" "data.frame"

## bug fixed
class(dt[, .N, by=x])
# [1] "foo"        "data.table" "data.frame"
```